# Javascript disappearing on refresh IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, refresh

I'm having some issues with Javascript content on Internet Explorer, specifically, a page will appear to be empty on refresh but if you open the page from a link it will display correctly.

- Site: [ABuenPaso.cr](http://www.abuenpaso.cr/index.php/login/?action=login)
- User: sof
- Pass: stackoverflow
- To go to the page with issues click on 'Registro' on the top menu.
- The calendar uses the [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin
- The reviews are Ajax calls to a php file
- General page usage instructions*

When the page first loads you'll be able to see a calendar with events and a weekly/monthly activity review. If you reload the page in IE, however, neither will show. Click on the 'Registro' button on the top menu again and they should display properly.

Also, in IE the form won't autocomplete in its entirety when clicking an event; the extra text areas that display when selecting 'Otros' in the 'Entrenamiento' and 'Tipo' drop-down menus won't show either.

Chrome and FF 3.6 are both working without a hitch (I've gotten some error reports from people using FF 3.5 but it worked fine for me). I've tried using the debugger that comes with IE8 but the only error reported is caused by an undefined variable used by a poll plugin that is used elsewhere.

The fact that the calendar/reviews work fine in Chrome/FF and will load on first entry at IE makes me think its not strictly a JS code problem. Other than that I have no clue what could be the problem and I've been stumped for a couple of days now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

---

General page usage instructions:

You can reach the page with problems by clicking on 'Registro' on the top menu bar and logging in with the information provided above.

The 'Aceptar' button will create a new event on the selected day, the only required values are 'Entrenamiento' and 'Tipo'.

The 'Borrar actividad' button will delete a selected event, it requires the 'Entrenamiento' to match the events value (this will set itself on Chrome/FF).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out IE wasn't executing the onload that loaded/executed the scripts. Moving this to a $(document).ready solved the problem.

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted (even though you answered it yourself) to help others who are looking for a similar problem. :-)